# Can I create root level shares from AD User Accounts?

Tags: active-directory, network-share, mac

Given a file structure for User accounts of `\\file-server\students\grad-year\user-home-folder`,  is it possible to create shares of `\\file-server\user-name`?

I have a Mac/Windows mixed environment. The Macs work much better with a root level share.

I can create the home folders in the users' directory in AD User Properties - Profile tab using `\\file-server\students\grad-year\%username%`. However, that seems to simply create the folder and not a true share. The file-server properties show the home folder as "Network Path: Not Shared".

I have about 2000 accounts to handle like this. So I'd like to find a way to automatically create true shares (like you'd create with Advanced Sharing).

Is that possible?

Comment: the profile tab in ADUC is a true share as \\server\students (then the remaining path is just a path within the share).  You map down to the username level with directory traversal, but only because the student accounts don't have rights at the "students" share level.

Comment: Oh yuck. That profile tab is a remnant from the Windows NT days. Avoid it!

Comment: Simple.  Use Samba.  Setting up a \\server\username share is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

### The actual answer to your question

> Given a file structure for User accounts of \file-server\students\grad-year\user-home-folder
>
> is it possible to create shares of \file-server\user-name

To answer your actual question, yes you can create one file share per student folder, and it will be mapped as `\\file-server\user1` for user1's folder, but maintaining that many shares is crazy talk. The ADUC profile tab will not do this for you. You will have to script it or do it manually.

You can map subdirectories of a share if you need to, so if you map all users' home folders to `H:\` you can just map `H:\` for User1 as `\\file-server\students\User1` if you follow my advice below, even though the `User1` folder itself isn't explicitly shared. This is a feature of file shares - you can map any subfolder directly, even if it isn't explicitly shared, as long as it is implicitly shared by virtue of a parent folder being shared.

Continue reading below for recommendations that will make your life infinitely easier.

---

### How you should consider laying out your file server

> I have about 2000 accounts to handle like this. So I'd like to find a way to automatically create true shares (like you'd create with Advanced Sharing...).

You don't want to have to maintain a separate share with separate share permissions for each user. That's lunacy. Have `\\file-server\students` shared with `Everyone - Full Control` in the share permissions and `Authenticated Users - Read - This folder only` in the NTFS permissions. Then, consider ditching the `grad-year` approach, as it only adds complexity and just have your hierarchy look like this:

```
-Students (NTFS Permissions: Authenticated Users - Read - This Folder Only | Administrators - Full Control | System - Full Control || Share Permissions: Authenticated Users - Full Control)  
---User1 (NTFS Permissions: User1 - Modify | Administrators - Full Control | System - Full Control)  
---User2 (NTFS Permissions: User2 - Modify | Administrators - Full Control | System - Full Control)
```

Trust me, I've dealt with this in many higher education environments. It becomes a huge PITA when you're doing anything other than `\\file-server\students\user1` and just sharing it out at `students`. Unless you have tens of thousands of student folders, you're overcomplicating it.

---

### Many shares v. one share

You say

> I have a Mac/Windows mixed environment. The Macs work much better with a root level share.

I've dealt very heavily in OS X/Windows mixed environments with OS X consuming Windows SMB shares and I've never heard of what you're describing. I'm going to assume that you're doing something crazy with permissions or have some nasty environmental stuff in play here, since how deep the folder is shouldn't matter one bit. There's really no benefit to having every single folder shared out. Really, stick to sharing the root folder and use NTFS permissions properly.

---

### Regarding the profiles tab in ADUC

You also say

> I  can create the home folders in the users' directory in AD User Properties - Profile tab using \file-server\students\grad-year\%username%.

Don't use the profiles tab in ADUC! It's from the Windows NT days! It's there for backwards compatibility and should not be used. You should use GPO for your Windows clients and WGM/MCX on your Macs to map these shares.

Comment: To add as an opinion.  I'd ditch the grad year as well and create the student accounts as LastnameStudentID# to avoid conflicts over the years and have a policy in place to kill off or empty the student's folder either after graduation or every year after school is out.

Comment: This depends wholly on your provisioning process. Having the folder named directly after the user allows for `%username%` to be used in scripts and GPOs, which is very very handy. As long as your accont provisioning policy is to never duplicate a previously used account name, this shouldn't be an issue. But, as always, YMMV.